# part 2 of limiting regexp_substr expressions

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

So with assistance the the other day-I have made strides but now challenged with a new issue- 
with the code below -I am trying to do two things-

> > 1) With the word car-if it is any other word -i.e. card, cardiac-do not return a false value.
> >
> > > 2) If there is punctuation, such a comma or period, between the terms then also do not return a value.

I have tried (^.) in various places w/out much success.

Any suggestions welcomed-

```
with test (id, col) as
      (select 1, 'Delivery in car. Brought'                   from dual union all
      select 2, 'we had delivered a nice card'                  from dual union all
      select 3, 'Born in the car blah blah blah' from dual union all
      select 4, 'having brought in by ambulance.  She had PN care'         from dual
      )
   select id,
     regexp_substr(col, '(born|birth|home|deliv\w+|ambulance|car).{0,20}(deliv\w+|birth|home|ambulance|car)',1,1,'i') result

  from test

results in 
    Delivery in car   -- correct 
    delivered a nice card --not correct. If the word is anything but car do not want result
    Born in the car - -correct 
    ambulance.  She had PN car --not correct. If there is punctuation that breaks up sentence then returns null value
```

Comment: You want to omit the rows with just "car" completely? Or what is the desired result here?

Comment: No. Omit anything where the word is not car in this case. Omit anything that has punctuation between the search terms

Answer (score 0):

Does this make sense?

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, 'Delivery in car. Brought'       from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'we had delivered a nice card'   from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Born in the car blah blah blah' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'having brought in by ambulance.  She had PN care' from dual
  6    )
  7  select id, col
  8  from test
  9  where regexp_instr(col, 'car(\.| )') > 0
 10    and regexp_instr(col, 'born|birth|home|delivery|ambulance', 1, 1, 1, 'i') > 0;

        ID COL
---------- ------------------------------------------------
         1 Delivery in car. Brought
         3 Born in the car blah blah blah

SQL>
```

Comment: Also the rows with punctuation at the end or beginning filtered in this case.

Comment: Does it work-yes! Thank you. Does it make sense-not yet.   See my reg_substr code above as car needs to be in tandem with other terms (i.e. born in car) -not sure if that makes sense-also need to use  reg_substr in this case-

Comment: Aha. How about yet another *popular* REGEXP_INSTR? I modified my code; have a look, please.

Comment: Def a vast improvement-and then if I add in the regexp_substr(col, '(born|birth|home|deliv\w+|ambulance|car).{0,20}(deliv\w+|birth|home|ambulance|car)',1,1,'i') result code above I think that should work- will test it out later and let you know- Thanks!

Comment: This would match the words `unborn`, `birthday`, `homeless`, etc. and the words `scar` or `vicar`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `(^|[^a-z])` to match either the start of the string or a non-alphabet character before the word you are matching and `([^a-z]|$)` to match a non-alphabet character or the end of the string after the word so that you do not match words like `vicar` or `unborn`:

```sql
with test (id, col) as (
  select 1, 'Delivery in car. Brought'                         from dual union all
  select 2, 'The car brought in the delivery.'                 from dual union all
  select 3, 'we had delivered a nice card'                     from dual union all
  select 4, 'Born in the car blah blah blah'                   from dual union all
  select 5, '"In the car, the born the baby was" said Yoda'    from dual union all
  select 6, 'having brought in by ambulance.  She had PN care' from dual union all
  select 7, 'The car brought the mother and unborn baby'       from dual union all
  select 8, 'The vicar said prayers for the baby.'             from dual
)
select id,
       col
from   test
where  REGEXP_LIKE( col, '(^|[^a-z])(born|birth|home|deliver(y|ed)||ambulance)([^a-z]|$)', 'i' )
and    REGEXP_LIKE( col, '(^|[^a-z])car([^a-z]|$)', 'i' )
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | COL                                          
> -: | :--------------------------------------------
>  1 | Delivery in car. Brought                     
>  2 | The car brought in the delivery.             
>  4 | Born in the car blah blah blah               
>  5 | "In the car, the born the baby was" said Yoda
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f415b694cae715ccbe7a07846336a743)*